# Samsung P2450H 24" display turns itself on & doesn't recognise DVI

Tags: dvi, vga

My Samsung P2450H 24" display is connected to DVI-port. Last night the display turned itself on showing a box "Analog...". This morning turned it on, complained "Check the signal cable". Disconnected and reconnected the cable, but it did not cure the situation. Replaced the DVI-cable with VGA-cable and it is OK now. No big deal, but I'd like to utilize DVI. Purchased it last August.

Just wondering could it be a display- / graphics card- / cable-related problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem using a stock Dell 19" monitor. What graphics card do you have?

Comment: @Joe Taylor: MSI NX8500GT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a viewsonic monitor (VP2030B) that had the same class of problem.  I think the problem was (in my case) that the monitor defaults to analogue, and the card will give up trying to transmit a DVI signal if it doesn't detect a DVI monitor.  Then the monitor gives up listening for DVI and drops to analouge mode.  As the video card is no longer transmitting a DVI signal the DVI on the monitor won't pick it up, even if you try to switch to DVI.  Much hilarity and nearly £1000 spent on different KVM switches ensues to no avail.  Monitor eventually replaced.

Get a DVI-D only cable, so it has no analogue signal to pick up.  If your problem is anything like mine, this should fix it.

Comment: Thanks. Had to install "MagicTune" software that came with the display. The firmware of the display can be manipulated with it and in this case the signal source / default timing settings were the reason for the confusion.

Comment: Welcome to the ranks of the [Stack Athletes](http://stackathlon.appspot.com/).